# Matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is symmetric and positively defined. Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is symmetric and positively defined. Then:
**a.** $A$ is similar to some diagonal matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$.
**b.** $A$ is similar to $I_n$
**c.** $A$ is congruent to $I_n$.

**b.** is of course false. Let's suppose by contradiction:
$A=C^{-1}I_nC = I_n$, it is obviously false.
**c.** It is true. Positvely defined symmetric matrix has a Cholesky decomposition. It means that $A=LI_nL^H$. Moreover, $L$ is non-singular due to fact that all diagonal entries (so eigenvalues) of $L$ are non-zero.  Hence, $A$ is congruent to $I_n$.
**a.** It is true,
Spectral theorem say:  Each normal matrix is unitary diagonalisable.  Symmetric matrixes (hermitian) are normal.  It means that $A=UDU^{H}=UDU{-1}$.  In case of hermitian ($A$ as symmetric is hermitian) matrix we know that entries of $D$  are real (so eigenvalues of $A$ are also real).
It seems to me that in case of **a.** assumption about positive definition isn't needed.

Tell me please, if my explanations are correct.

Comment: all your sayes are true, you need positivity only to use Cholesky decomposition

Comment: By *postively defined* I assume you mean *positive definite*?

Comment: yes, you get it.